# How do I change color of specific text in CSS code

Tags: css

I don't know anything about CSS coding but I'm using "User CSS" extension for Chrome to highlight some of the values in the report. I go to 'inspect' from my browser to find the id of things that I want to highlight and then use that in User CSS extension to make the change. The code looks like this.

```
#ctl00676_Content_rptSummaryCol1_ctl6787_lblFieldData1{
   color: blue;
}
```

Now I want to highlight a specific text for this id. this id could have values of "Email, phone, text". I want Email to be red, phone to be blue and text to be green color in my report. Can anyone help me with this? I do I add this specifications into my code?

Comment: can you provide example html. If the text is all in a single component doing exactly what you want may be impossible

Comment: Use a greasemonkey script to wrap the three strings inside three spans. There is no pure css solution I am afraid.